# How to separate each sub group in main group Array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array. It contains several subgroups. Example:

```
let mainArray=[50,51,52,53,54,511,512,513,514,521,522,523,524,525,526,527]
```

I want to divide that main array into sub-arrays.For example

```
sub1 =[50,51,52,53,54]
sub2 =[511,512,513,514]
sub3 =[521,522,523,524,525,526,527]
```

Can you help me?

Comment: you want to split on the basis of what?

Comment: Seems like he needs to have consecutive numbers separated in each array

Comment: it is unclear how the split should be done, there must be some logic for the splitting, for example the first array contains numbers that are two digits.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal good catch, so i guess `50-59` `511-519` `520-529` but we it is purely a guess unless the op says so.

Comment: @Dementic yes its not default array .this data coming from backend  server

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal  this array  values like login user privilege permissions so its every time changing .ex(530-532,540-548,...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Array reduce function :

```js
let mainArray=[50,51,52,53,54,511,512,513,514,521,522,523,524,525,526,527];

let groups = mainArray.reduce ( 
  (grps, el, i, main) => ((el === main[i-1] + 1 ? grps[0].push (el)
                                                : grps.unshift ([el])), grps), []);

[sub3, sub2, sub1] = groups;

console.log (sub1, sub2, sub3);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer .  its working fine but i need to give  separate  array name also for identifying .Any Suggestions

Comment: The result array provides all groups regardless of number, for the names your must know how many groups are generated.

Comment: Ah destructured assigns, very useful but equivalent to : sub3 = groups[0]; sub2=groups[2]; sub1 = groups[3];

Answer (score 2):

This will create an Array of Subarays:

```js
const arr = [50,51,52,53,54, 511,512,513,514, 521,522,523,524,525,526,527];
let newArr = [];
let temp = [arr[0]];

for (let index = 1; index < arr.length; index++) {
  if (arr[index] == arr[index - 1] + 1) {
    temp.push(arr[index]);
  } else {
    newArr.push(temp);
    temp = [];
  }
  
  if (index == arr.length - 1) {
    newArr.push(temp);
  }
}

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: Beat me to it, it was a nice exercise though.

Comment: @Dementic we shall meet again in some other questions! :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [50,51,52,53,54,511,512,513,514,521,522,523,524,525,526,527];
var result = [],
    lastVal = -1;
while(arr.length) {
  var currentIndex = arr.length - 1;
  var currentValue = arr[currentIndex];
  var c = Math.floor(currentValue/10);
  if (c !== lastVal) {
    lastVal = c;
    result.push([currentValue]);
  }else{
    result[result.length-1].push(currentValue);
  }
  arr.splice(currentIndex, 1);
}
result.forEach(function(arr){ arr.reverse(); });
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Here's a solution using Ramda.js

```js
const x = [50,51,52,53,54,511,512,513,514,521,522,523,524,525,526,527]

const f = R.pipe(
  R.sortBy(R.identity), 
  R.groupWith(R.pipe(R.subtract, Math.abs, R.equals(1)))
)

console.log(f(x))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```